# Python: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

tengo estas listas de igual longitud

```
listaP=df['EP'] 
listaT=df['Total']
listaS=df['Semana']
```

y busco llenar estas dos listas

```
listaSinRevisar=[]
listaPagado=[]
```

con la sumatoria de listaT que tengan el mismo valor de listaS, (si listaP es igual a 0, se suma a listaPagado, si es 0 se suma a listaSinRevisar)

```
tope=len(listaP)
tope1=tope-1
a=0
b=0
c=1

while a<=tope1:
    if listaS[a]==listaS[c]:
        if listaP[a]==1:
            listaPagado[b]=listaPagado[b]+listaT[a]
        else:
            listaSinRevisar[b]=listaSinRevisar[a]+listaT[a]
    else:
        b=b+1
        if listaP[a]==1:
            listaPagado[b]=listaPagado[b]+listaT[a]
        else:
            listaSinRevisar[b]=listaSinRevisar[a]+listaT[a]

    a=a+1
    c=c+1
```

Me arroja este error y no encuentro la razon, la longitud de las listas es la misma

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-cdba56c494a0> in <module>
     15     if listaS[a]==listaS[c]:
     16         if listaP[a]==1:
---> 17             listaPagado[b]=listaPagado[b]+listaT[a]
     18         else:
     19             listaSinRevisar[b]=listaSinRevisar[a]+listaT[a]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Ese error significa que al ir iterando por una listas, te has salido de su rango. Por ejemplo tienes una lista con cinco elementos  intentas acceder al sexto elemento, no puedes porque no existe y te da el error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

`listaPagado` es una lista vacía, en cuanto `b` es 1 eso ya hace que te salte el error que comentas dado que intentas acceder a un índice que no existe.

Ejemplo:

```py
a = []
b = 1

a[b] = 1
# Error!
```

El código que pones no es nada claro en lo que intentas conseguir así que no estoy muy seguro que tan útil serán estos consejos.

Puedes inicializar `listaPagado` con una cantidad de elementos de la siguiente forma:

```py
a = [0] * 2

a[1] = 1
# Ok!
```

Si lo que quieres es añadir un elemento nuevo a la lista:

```py
a = []
a.append(1)
```